# Backbone view call function in same view

Tags: javascript, function, backbone.js, view, undefined

I have:

```
app.views.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

   ...

func1: function () {
    //do something
},

func2: function () {
    func1();
},

});
```

Probably I am doing it all wrong but I just want to call func1 from func2 and this says func2 is undefined.

Comment: It should be `this.func1()`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Need to bind func1 in initialize to the scope of the view that func2 is in:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'func2');
```